# mvn dependency resolution error after install

Tags: maven, dependencies, installation, resolution, artifactnotfoundexception

pretty basic mistake: I defined the path for the jar file to be installed wrong in the first batch call. so SOLVED.

I'm trying to install and use a JDBC-DB2 driver for my database application. It seems like there is no repository for this, so I tried to install the driver file (db2jcc4.jar) and the licence (db2jcc_license_cu.jar) i got with the following batch file:

```
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=db2jcc4.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 -DartifactId=db2jcc4 -Dversion=3.1.57 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
call mvn install:install-file -Dfile=db2jcc_license_cu.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2 -DartifactId=db2jcc_license_cu -Dversion=3.1.57 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

which worked pretty well (Build::Sucess)

But when I tried to access the files in my project by adding them to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.57</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.57</version>
</dependency>
```

and call

```
mvn compile
```

then I get a

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hibernate-tutorial: Could not resolve
dependencies for project org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:jar:1.0.0-SN
APSHOT: Failure to find com.ibm.db2:db2jcc4:jar:3.1.57 in http://repo.maven.apac
he.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattem
pted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [
Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I'm not familiar with maven, but apparently it tries to resolve the dependency in the central and doesn't find them in my local repo, that's the point I wanna ask u for help ;)

(and yes guys, database applicaion means hibernate tutorial (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html) in this context :D)

EDIT:

detailed error report:

```
mvn -X compile

Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:
28+0100)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.5

Java version: 1.7.0_17, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foun
dation\apache-maven-3.0.5\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\MyName\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\maven\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for C:\mav
en\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:
jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.co
re, parent: null]
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] The expression ${artifactId} is deprecated. Please use ${project.artif
actId} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
he stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
g such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [compile]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building First Hibernate Tutorial 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-so
urces, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate
-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resou
rces, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-in
tegration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy
]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-so
urces, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate
-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resou
rces, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-in
tegration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy
]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-so
urces, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate
-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resou
rces, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-in
tegration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy
]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile]
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/mave
n2, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/mave
n2, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resou
rces (default-resources)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <buildFilters default-value="${project.build.filters}"/>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encodin
g>
  <escapeString>${maven.resources.escapeString}</escapeString>
  <escapeWindowsPaths default-value="true">${maven.resources.escapeWindowsPaths}
</escapeWindowsPaths>
  <includeEmptyDirs default-value="false">${maven.resources.includeEmptyDirs}</i
ncludeEmptyDirs>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <overwrite default-value="false">${maven.resources.overwrite}</overwrite>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <resources default-value="${project.resources}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <supportMultiLineFiltering default-value="false">${maven.resources.supportMult
iLineFiltering}</supportMultiLineFiltering>
  <useBuildFilters default-value="true"/>
  <useDefaultDelimiters default-value="true"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:comp
ile (default-compile)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <buildDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <classpathElements default-value="${project.compileClasspathElements}"/>
  <compileSourceRoots default-value="${project.compileSourceRoots}"/>
  <compilerId default-value="javac">${maven.compiler.compilerId}</compilerId>
  <compilerVersion>${maven.compiler.compilerVersion}</compilerVersion>
  <debug default-value="true">${maven.compiler.debug}</debug>
  <debuglevel>${maven.compiler.debuglevel}</debuglevel>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encodin
g>
  <executable>${maven.compiler.executable}</executable>
  <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.compiler.failOnError}</failOnError>
  <fork default-value="false">${maven.compiler.fork}</fork>
  <generatedSourcesDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/generated
-sources/annotations"/>
  <maxmem>${maven.compiler.maxmem}</maxmem>
  <meminitial>${maven.compiler.meminitial}</meminitial>
  <optimize default-value="false">${maven.compiler.optimize}</optimize>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <outputFileName>${project.build.finalName}</outputFileName>
  <projectArtifact default-value="${project.artifact}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <showDeprecation default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showDeprecation}</show
Deprecation>
  <showWarnings default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showWarnings}</showWarnin
gs>
  <source default-value="1.5">${maven.compiler.source}</source>
  <staleMillis default-value="0">${lastModGranularityMs}</staleMillis>
  <target default-value="1.5">${maven.compiler.target}</target>
  <verbose default-value="false">${maven.compiler.verbose}</verbose>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata javax.servlet:servlet-api/maven-metadata.xml in
local (C:\maven\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for javax.servlet:servlet-api/maven-metadata
.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata javassist:javassist/maven-metadata.xml in local
(C:\maven\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for javassist:javassist/maven-metadata.xml,
locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]    org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.1.GA:compile
[DEBUG]       antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[DEBUG]          xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[DEBUG]       javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]    javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.5.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[DEBUG]    javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[DEBUG]    org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.9:compile
[DEBUG]    com.ibm.db2:db2jcc4:jar:3.1.57:compile
[DEBUG]    com.ibm.db2:db2jcc_license_cu:jar:3.1.57:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.432s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 24 00:12:09 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hibernate-tutorial: Could not resolve
dependencies for project org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:jar:1.0.0-SN
APSHOT: Failure to find com.ibm.db2:db2jcc4:jar:3.1.57 in http://repo.maven.apac
he.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattem
pted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [
Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
n project hibernate-tutorial: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.hib
ernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.ibm.
db2:db2jcc4:jar:3.1.57 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval o
f central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAr
eResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not res
olve dependencies for project org.hibernate.tutorials:hibernate-tutorial:jar:1.0
.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.ibm.db2:db2jcc4:jar:3.1.57 in http://repo.maven
.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be re
attempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure
 to find com.ibm.db2:db2jcc4:jar:3.1.57 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 w
as cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepe
ndencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure t
o find com.ibm.db2:db2jcc4:jar:3.1.57 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was
 cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the up
date interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Def
aultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArti
facts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDepe
ndencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to fi
nd com.ibm.db2:db2jcc4:jar:3.1.57 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cac
hed in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
 interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newExcept
ion(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:230)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArti
fact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:204)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(Def
aultArtifactResolver.java:427)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
```

Comment: can you run `mvn -X compile` and paste the results here? Thanks.

Comment: added it. (edit in the question)

Comment: Thanks. Can you look in `C:\maven\repository` under the path `com/ibm/db2/db2jcc4/3.1.57`, and see if the `db2jcc4.jar` file is there, and if not can you tell us if any of the path is there? If it is, can you run `mvn -o compile`?

Comment: Thank u, that helped me alot, it apparently installed the license correctly but the path in the mvn install to "db2jcc4.jar" was incorrect (so it added no jar in the repo), dunno why i got a success message even though? it works fine now ty alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty basic mistake: i defined the path for the jar file to be installed wrong in the first batch call.